# Why am I losing my last empty character with .innerText?

Tags: javascript, innertext

I need to get the content a cell in a one-column table.
When I use `.innerText` I lose the last empty character. Here is my code :

When I want to display my object (raw) :

```
console.log(myRow);
```

I get (with last character of cell empty) :

```
<tr class="t-state-selected">
    <td>Some data </td>
</tr>
```

But when I want the innetText :

```
console.log("'" + myRow.innerText + "'");
```

I get :

```
'Some data'
```

Why am I losing this last empty space ? How can I get all the data?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with `tr = document.createElement('tr'); tr.innerHTML = '<td>Some data </td>'; tr.innerText; // "Some data "`

Comment: Isn't that what `&nbsp;` is used for?

Comment: @Uxonith "Some data " comes from a DB, I think I'll create a lot of issues with `&nbsp;` but I can try it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using .textContent instead of .innerText which trims it.

Or if you need <IE9 support you could perhaps use .innerHTML